# use react to remove object in dynamic form

Tags: reactjs

I've created a dynamic form that adapts to my changes, allowing me to add, remove, and modify objects and input fields as needed. However, my remove function isn't functioning correctly. Although it deletes the appropriate element in the Value variable when I press the delete button on one of the items in the [landing zone environments].map, it removes the wrong input field in the UI.

As an example, let me demonstrate:
I generate three `[landing zone environments]`. You can view the corresponding input fields in my form, and I'll display my `Value` variable in JSON format below:
[image]
[image]

I then delete the middle, but the UI does not show according to whats now in the `value`
[image]
[image]

This is the remove function:

```html
    const handleremove = (i) => {
        const list = [...value['Landing Zone Environments']];
        list.splice(i, 1);
        setValue({ ...value, ['Landing Zone Environments']: list });
    }
```

And the html where i map through the [Landing Zones Enviroments]:

```html
{
                        value['Landing Zone Environments'].map((x, i) => (
                                <div key={i}>
                                    <div>
                                        <label >Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="Name" required={false} placeholder="Example: prod" onChange={e => handleinputchange(e, i)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label >Advisor Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="Advisor Email" placeholder="Example: advisor@invalid.xyz" onChange={e => handleinputchange(e, i)} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="minus_button" onClick={() => handleremove(i)}>-</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                                             ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't use images of code/json when you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove an item from an array and respect immutability (see this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-react-should-you-mutate-objects/)), the best practice is using the .filter() method, which returns a new array based on the old array and the filter condition:

```
const handleremove = (i) => {
    const list = value['Landing Zone Environments'].filter((item, index) => index !== i)
    setValue({ ...value, ['Landing Zone Environments']: list });
}
```

Comment: i tried to change the function to this, but it did not fix the problem, the UI still deletes the wrong one